# Entering value to database after pressing enter from a textbox

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, textbox, buttonclick

I am working with windows form application c# i Have created some text boxes and i want to send those values to data base it is all working after a button click but i need to enter all the values to the database after pressing enter from a text box. any idea??

```
                // Adding Values to Data Base
                string mySQL = "INSERT INTO Stock_Entry VALUES ("
                    + textBox_ItemId.Text + ", '"
                    + textBox_Ctgry.Text.Trim() + "','"
                    + textBox_ItmNme.Text.Trim() + "','"
                    + textBox_UntPrc.Text.Trim() + "','"
                    + textBox_Stock.Text.Trim() + "','"
                    + dateTimePicker_StkInDat.Text.Trim() + "','"
                    + textBox_Store.Text.Trim() + "','"
                    + textBox_StlLktn.Text.Trim() + "')";

                DBConnection database = new DBConnection();
                int rslt = database.insertValues(mySQL);`
```

Comment: You have to give us more information and code examples of what you have done. Which database are you using? Personally I would use SQL server + Entity framework + the repository pattern to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Your problem is not clearly identified and you are not telling if you have any errors so I think `KeyDown` is what you need in the button event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for this `KeyDown` event

```
 private void YourTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
 String connection= "Data Source=YourServer;Initial Catalog=YourDatabase;user=User;password=YourPassword;Integrated Security=True;";
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
string insertCmdText = "INSERT INTO table(column1)values(@valueForColumn1)";
SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(insertCmdText,connection);
sqlCom.Paramaters.AddWithValue("@valueForColumn1",YourTextBox.Text);
connection.Open();
sqlCom.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

But consider that saving into Database after KeyPress event is not a right way to go.

For your future questions please provide your code.

Comment: thanks mark i think i can handle inserting data to database coz i am have passed with a button click but i need to make key down in event i have  search but no idea plz help me

Comment: @user2979006 if you cant find Event Tab in Visual Studio and you see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwwsdtbk(v=vs.110).asp It will guide you where to find the Event Tab to create Events. In the `Properties` window click `Events` and `doubleclick` desired one

Answer (score 2):

You can Handle `KeyDown` Event of your `TextBox` Control to achieve this.

Sample Code:

```
    private void TextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {

                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    // call function here to Insert TextBox1 data into database
                    InsertMyData(TextBox1.Text.ToString());    
                }
            }

            private void InsertMyData(String value1)
            {
              //Insert Data into database
              String strCon = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=mydatabase;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;Integrated Security=True;";
             using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(strCon))
             {
                String strCmd = "insert into mytable(value1) value(@myvalue1)";
                    using (SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand(strCmd, sqlCon))
                    {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myvalue1", value1);
                    sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    }
              }                 
            }
```

if you want more info please let me know your scenario.

Comment: hope it will help me but when i double click on it it is giving me text change only please guide me how to make it.

Comment: @user2979006 please post here your code so we can help you.

Comment: @user2979006: please show us how you are inserting.

Comment: when you double click on it, means on what textbox or some other button, sorry i could not understand. could you please elaborate bit more?

Comment: this is how i am entering the data to database by button click i am having my connection string in my DB_Connection

Comment: @user2979006: did you share any image or code sorry i could not see :(

Comment: i Cudnt add my code here

Comment: @user2979006: you can edit your Question itself.

Comment: @user2979006: your question was put on hold as you didnot share your effort or code please try again and properly state your problem and share your code :) Have a nice day

Comment: mhhhh :( b tnx for ur effort on me thanks a lot